# The Gui menu to create widgets is not appearing in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

It always appeared, but then out of the blue on one new project it wasn't there. I have double checked it was a QWidgets project, and it was.

Comment: Do you mean in the Design view of Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

Open Qt Creator, go to the tap: Window > Views >  And check "Widget box"